# store JSON encoded object in Redis

Tags: php, node.js, redis, in-memory-database

I am using laravel Redis cache facade to push my object data(JSON encoded) to Redis and using node.js redis module to get back the data using key search.
My JSON string is getting stored in the Redis like this `s:2257:"{"footer_finders":{"footer_block1_finders":[{"_id":1803,"slug":"pqr","title":"xyz","finder_coverimag`.Here the string `s:2257` is the pain for me ,as it is breaaking my JSON parse on the node.Redis is storing my json_encoded string appended with some `s:random_number`.

Any suggestions how to fix this or should i look at other datatype of redis(list  or hash) instead of string?

Thanks

Comment: The `s:2257` is not added by Redis. This is probably done your Laravel cache handler.

Comment: Yes the issue seems to come from resolution difference between PHP serializer and NodeJs JSON deserializer..

Answer (score 0):

you can override the current encoding type in the for serializer for redis. Apparently predis in laravel don't have any support to change the serailizer for objects in redis